# What does the Bash operator <<< (i.e. triple less than sign) mean?

Tags: bash, shell, herestring

What does the triple-less-than-sign bash operator, `<<<`, mean, as inside the following code block?

```
LINE="7.6.5.4"
IFS=. read -a ARRAY <<< "$LINE"
echo "$IFS"
echo "${ARRAY[@]}"
```

Also, why does `$IFS` remain to be a space, not a period?

Comment: Another use of this operator (instead of named pipes with mknod)  when you need multiple pipes in a single | pipline: eg. echo data | command --data-on-stdin  --other-data-on-fd-3   3<<<'other-data'

Answer (score 56, accepted):

It redirects the string to stdin of the command.

Variables assigned directly before the command in this way only take effect for the command process; the shell remains untouched.

Comment: How do I modify it to use a custom multichar delimiter? Say, `==>`? How should I quote the string?

Comment: You can't. `$IFS` is always interpreted as a series of single characters.

Comment: But when I want to split the array using newline. Only the first item is getting added to the hostArray. But the host has 4 items. `host=$(mysql -S $socket $catalog --skip-column-names -e "select host from mysql.user); echo "Host: $host"; IFS=$'\n';read -ra hostArray <<< "$host"; echo "HostArray:$hostArray" #This prints only 1 item. But there are 4 items;` What is wrong here?

Comment: @Guna I'm a few years too late but anyway others might wonder so...in this part `<<< "$host"` , when you reference an array like `"$host"` it implies the default index of zero so it's really doing `"$host[0]"`. What you need there is `"${host[@]}"`

Comment: Please note that this syntax is [not in POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07).

Answer (score 18):

From `man bash`

> Here Strings
>     A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> ```
>      <<<word
> ```
>
> The word is expanded and supplied to the command on its standard input.

<strike>The `.` on the IFS line is equivalent to `source` in bash.</strike>

**Update:** More from `man bash` (Thanks gsklee, sehe)

> IFS    The Internal Field Separator that is  used  for  word  splitting
>      after  expansion  and  to  **split  lines into words with the read
>      builtin  command**.   The  default  value  is  "`<space><tab><new‐line>`".

yet more from `man bash`

> The  environment  for  any  simple command or function may be augmented
>   temporarily by prefixing it with parameter  assignments,  as  described
>   above in PARAMETERS.  These assignment statements affect only the environment seen by that command.

Comment: The `.` seems like a way to define a custom delimiter for `$LINE`

Answer (score 3):

The reason that IFS is not being set is that bash isn't seeing that as a separate command... you need to put a line feed or a semicolon after the command in order to terminate it:

```
$ cat /tmp/ifs.sh
LINE="7.6.5.4"
IFS='.'  read -a ARRAY <<< "$LINE"
echo "$IFS"
echo "${ARRAY[@]}"

$ bash /tmp/ifs.sh 


7 6 5 4
```

but

```
$ cat /tmp/ifs.sh 
LINE="7.6.5.4"
IFS='.';  read -a ARRAY <<< "$LINE"
echo "$IFS"
echo "${ARRAY[@]}"

$ bash /tmp/ifs.sh 
.
7 6 5 4
```

I'm not sure why doing it the first way wasn't a syntax error though.

Comment: Because the first way is how you temporarily set env vars for a single command. They automatically reset back to their previous values when that command is complete.  I use this all the time to set debug flags or what have you but only temporarily.

Answer (score 3):

Just to provide a cleaner example of `<<<` without considering `read`, when you do:

```
mycmd <<< $myvar
```

seems to be equivalent to:

```
printf '%s\n' "$myvar" | mycmd
```

which is similar to:

```
echo "$myvar" | mycmd
```

except that `echo` interprets some backslash escapes and therefore could mess up your string.

So we see that `<<<` is a convenient and concise way to pass a variable (or other expansions) to the stdin of a command.

As a concrete example:

```
myvar="$(printf '01\n23\n45')"
sed 's/./A/' <<< $myvar
```

or:

```
sed 's/./A/' <<< $'01\n23\n45'
```

or:

```
myvar="$(printf '01\n23\n45')"
printf '%s\n' "$myvar" | sed 's/./A/'
```

all use `sed` to replace the first letter of each line with `A` giving output:

```
A1
A3
A5
```