# How to read a space-delimited string into an array in Bash?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, delimiter

I have a variable which contains a space-delimited string:

```
line="1 1.50 string"
```

I want to split that string with space as a delimiter and store the result in an array, so that the following:

```
echo ${arr[0]}
echo ${arr[1]}
echo ${arr[2]}
```

outputs

```
1
1.50
string
```

Somewhere I found a solution which doesn't work:

```
arr=$(echo ${line})
```

If I run the echo statements above after this, I get:

```
1 1.50 string
[empty line]
[empty line]
```

I also tried

```
IFS=" "
arr=$(echo ${line})
```

with the same result. Can someone help, please?

Comment: See this answer on Unix & Linux Stack Exchange: [Using sed with herestring (<<<) and read -a](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/153335/201820). `set -f; arr=($string); set +f` seems to be faster than `read -r -a <<< $string`.

Comment: Related: how to convert a _newline-delimited_ string to a bash array: [Convert multiline string to array](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24628076/4561887)

Comment: See also these demonstrations and examples here: [`shellcheck` SC2206: Quote to prevent word splitting/globbing, or split robustly with `mapfile` or `read -a`.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206)

Answer (score 441, accepted):

In order to convert a string into an array, create an array from the string, letting the string get split naturally according to the `IFS` (Internal Field Separator) variable, which is the space char by default:

```
arr=($line)
```

or pass the string to the stdin of the `read` command using the [herestring](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7950268/4561887) (`<<<`) operator:

```
read -a arr <<< "$line"
```

For the first example, it is crucial *not* to use quotes around `$line` since that is what allows the string to get split into multiple elements.

See also: https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206

Comment: and to do a sanity check of your beautiful new array: `for i in ${arr[@]}; do echo $i; done`

Comment: or just `echo ${arr[@]}`

Comment: Both ways may fail if `$line` has globbing characters in it. `mkdir x && cd x && touch A B C && line="*" arr=($line); echo ${#arr[@]}` gives 3

Comment: `declare -a "arr=($line)"` will ignore `IFS` delimiters inside quoted strings

Comment: Both solutions work for me on the cmd-line. `arr=($line)` doesn't work for me within a bash script whereas `read -a arr <<<$line` does.

Comment: What need to be done if the file was delimited eg :"1,1.50,string" . Can delimite be specified before feeding to array.

Comment: @Awknewbie try this command: `arr=($(echo '1,1.50,string' | tr ',' ' '))`

Comment: Works also with ksh.
Beware that declaring `arr=("a b")` won't work, you need to explicitly declare the intermediary variable "line".
`line="a b"`
then 
`arr=($line)`

Comment: You can avoid wildcard expansion with: set -f && arr=($line) && set +f

Comment: @Tino  No.  When `line='*'`, `read -a arr <<<$line` always work, but only `arr=($line)` fails.

Comment: @JohnnyWong Good find!  Sorry that I mixed that with `ksh` where `a='*'; read -A b <<<$a` fails while `a='*'; read -A b <<<"$a"` works.   Note that `bash` uses `read -a` while `ksh` uses `read -A`.

Comment: Shellcheck SC2207 argues against `arr=($line)`. I like how concise this is, but maybe it's not worth using?

Comment: [shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) says that it should be `read -r -a` instead of just `read -a`

Answer (score 62):

In: `arr=( $line )`. The "split" comes associated with "glob".
Wildcards (`*`,`?` and `[]`) will be expanded to matching filenames.

The correct solution is only slightly more complex:

```
IFS=' ' read -a arr <<< "$line"
```

No globbing problem; the split character is set in `$IFS`, variables quoted.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  The statement `arr=($line)` in the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294015/6862601) suffers from globbing issues.  For example, try: `line="twinkling *"; arr=($line); declare -p arr`.

Comment: Quoting is optional for herestring, `<<<` but it may be a good idea to still use double quotes for consistency and readability.

Comment: See also: [`shellcheck` SC2206: Quote to prevent word splitting/globbing, or split robustly with `mapfile` or `read -a`.](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2206)

Comment: I get `func:read:5: bad option: -a`

Answer (score 61):

Try this:

```
arr=(`echo ${line}`);
```

Comment: Nice -- This solution also works in Z shell where some of the other approaches above fail.

Comment: Its does the work, could you please explain why it works?

Comment: Remark: this doesn't work either when the line have '*' in it, like `line='*'`

Comment: Looking for a `GNU Make 4.2.1` solution, but it doesn't did the job

Comment: @artu-hnrq Make use the `sh` shell. That shell has no arrays. The question is about arrays. Can't give you an answer compatible with both requirements. Unless you claim that the positional arguments are the only array in `sh` and, then, this: `set -- $line; printf '%s\n' "$@"` would work. Note that glob characters are still a problem in this case.

Comment: You are right @Isaac! I made my [own question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66233239/2989289)

Comment: This solution worked for me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Very simple solution for CentOS8

Answer (score 16):

If you need parameter expansion, then try:

```
eval "arr=($line)"
```

For example, take the following code.

```
line='a b "c d" "*" *'
eval "arr=($line)"
for s in "${arr[@]}"; do 
    echo "$s"
done
```

If the current directory contained the files `a.txt`, `b.txt` and `c.txt`, then executing the code would produce the following output.

```
a
b
c d
*
a.txt
b.txt
c.txt
```

Comment: Looking for a `GNU Make 4.2.1` solution, but is not that

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution, but using `readarray`:

```
readarray -d ' ' arr <<< "argelia china denmark colombia"
```

Indeed, storing the input in an array of 4 positions:

```
$ echo ${#arr[@]} ${arr[@]:1:2}
4 china  denmark
```

Answer (score -9):

```
line="1 1.50 string"

arr=$( $line | tr " " "\n")

for x in $arr
do
echo "> [$x]"
done
```

Comment: The looping is wrong, it splits the array fine and the pipe into `tr` is superfluous but it should loop over `"${arr[@]}"` instead, not `$arr`