# How do I iterate through each line of a command's output in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a script that reads from `/proc/stat` and calculates CPU usage. There are three relevant lines in `/proc/stat`:

```
cpu  1312092 24 395204 12582958 77712 456 3890 0 0 0
cpu0 617029 12 204802 8341965 62291 443 2718 0 0 0
cpu1 695063 12 190402 4240992 15420 12 1172 0 0 0
```

Currently, my script only reads the first line and calculates usage from that:

```
cpu=($( cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu[^0-9] ' ))
unset cpu[0]
idle=${cpu[4]}
total=0
for value in "${cpu[@]}"; do
  let total=$(( total+value ))
done

let usage=$(( (1000*(total-idle)/total+5)/10 ))
echo "$usage%"
```

This works as expected, because the script only parses this line:

```
cpu  1312092 24 395204 12582958 77712 456 3890 0 0 0
```

It's easy enough to get only the lines starting with `cpu0` and `cpu1`

```
cpu=$( cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu[0-9] ' )
```

but I don't know how to iterate over each line and apply this same process. Ive tried resetting the internal field separator inside a subshell, like this:

```
cpus=$( cat /proc/stat | grep '^cpu[0-9] ' )
(
IFS=$'\n'
for cpu in $cpus; do
    cpu=($cpu)
    unset cpu[0]
    idle=${cpu[4]}
    total=0
    for value in "${cpu[@]}"; do
        let total=$(( total+value ))
    done
    let usage=$(( (1000*(total-idle)/total+5)/10 ))
    echo -n "$usage%"
done
)
```

but this gets me a syntax error

```
line 18: (1000*(total-idle)/total+5)/10 : division by 0 (error token is "+5)/10 ")
```

If I echo the `cpu` variable in the loop it looks like it's separating the lines properly. I looked at [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9294015/2766558) and I think Im assigning the cpu variable to an array properly but is there another error Im not seeing?

I put my script into [whats wrong with my script](http://www.whatswrongwithmyscript.com) and it doesnt show me any errors apart from a warning about using `cat` within `$()`, s o I'm stumped.

Comment: I think you should try doing this in `awk`.

Comment: @Staven I'll look into that. Is something like this pretty much a one  liner in awk?

Comment: @user30588 I added an `awk` solution too in my answer

Comment: @janos Thanks for the reminder. Your bash answer is helpful, although the `awk` script in the other answer is superior to the one-line `awk` script in your answer.

Comment: @user30588 you're welcome. I don't know what you mean by "superior" though, his solution is equivalent, only the syntax is different.

Comment: @janos The non-one-liner code is more readable, and takes advantage of the fact that `awk` allows for floating-point division. The `(1000 * (total - idle) / total + 5) / 10` hack that I used in my bash code (and that's in your `awk` code) isn't necessary in `awk`. It just adds clutter.

Comment: @user30588 hm, ok that's true

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change this line in the middle of your loop:

```
IFS=' ' cpu=($cpu)
```

You need this because outside of your loop you're setting `IFS=$'\n', but with that setting`cpu($cpu)` won't do what you expect.

Btw, I would write your script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

grep ^cpu /proc/stat | while IFS=$'\n' read cpu; do
    cpu=($cpu)
    name=${cpu[0]}
    unset cpu[0]
    idle=${cpu[4]}
    total=0
    for value in "${cpu[@]}"; do
        ((total+=value))
    done
    ((usage=(1000 * (total - idle) / total + 5) / 10))
    echo "$name $usage%"
done
```

The equivalent using `awk`:

```
awk '/^cpu/ { total=0; idle=$5; for (i=2; i<=NF; ++i) { total += $i }; print $1, int((1000 * (total - idle) / total + 5) / 10) }' < /proc/stat
```

Comment: Everything is a one-liner if you delete the newlines.

Comment: Don't know why you said that. It was natural for me to write this on one line, I'm not arguing it's better to write on one line. I see you wrote pretty much the same thing but expanded to multiple lines, which is more readable.

Answer (score 3):

Because the OP asked, an `awk` program.

```
awk '
    /cpu[0-9] .*/ {
        total = 0
        idle = $5
        for(i = 0; i <= NF; i++) { total += $i; }
        printf("%s: %f%%\n", $1, 100*(total-idle)/total);
    }
' /proc/stat
```

The `/cpu[0-9] .*/` means "execute for every line matching this expression".
The variables like `$1` do what you'd expect, but the 1st field has index 1, not 0: `$0` means the whole line in `awk`.

Comment: Does awk not have the rounding issues that bash has? That's why I used `(1000 * (total - idle) / total + 5) / 10` instead of just `100*(total-idle)/total`

Comment: @user30588 I don't know. What rounding issues does Bash have? Regardless though, I've put the wrong format letter in the printf, fixed now.

Comment: `bash` doesn't have rounding issues so much as it only performs integer division: `a/b` is always an integer, with the remainder thrown out.

Comment: Then no, `awk` doesn't have such a limitation. Try `awk 'BEGIN { print 1/2; }' /dev/null`, for example.