# Assigning variables in a for loop

Tags: bash, shell, loops, unix, scripting

Ive got a file called school.test and it looks like this:

```
David       maths
Sam         maths
Sam         english
Simon       french
Simon       english
```

I want to write a for loop which reads this txt file up line by line and assign values that it is reading up on that line to different variables and run it through a command. Problem is I don't know how to set the first value as a variable and the second value as a different variable.

For example for the first line the for loop reads it would look something like this:

```
for line in `cat/home/school.test`
do
positionClient -name [variable=David] -class [variable=math]
done
```

and so on and so forth. How do I do this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293887/in-bash-how-do-i-convert-a-space-delimited-string-into-an-array  might help

Comment: I have no idea what the title has to do with the question.

Comment: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001

Comment: is this an exercise, or a practical (e.g. work, non-school, non-training) problem?  i'll reserve the right to "solve the problem", rather than answer the question.   why?  unless the OP states something to the effect:  'this is a problem designed to show how to ..." i can assume that's NOT the point, and the problem's solution MAY be better solved by another means.   at the very least this should get a. the problem posers to make more relevant examples, and b. the problem solvers to be open about their needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ while read name subject
> do
>   echo "Name: $name, Subject: $subject"
> done <<< 'David       maths
> Sam         maths
> Sam         english
> Simon       french
> Simon       english'
Name: David, Subject: maths
Name: Sam, Subject: maths
Name: Sam, Subject: english
Name: Simon, Subject: french
Name: Simon, Subject: english
```

Just redirect from a file instead of a herestring when you want to do the real thing.

Comment: so I'm trying this method but its not working for me:
     `while read name subject
     do
     echo "symbol: $symbol";
     echo "inventory: $inventory"
     done <<< /srg/pro/data//school.txt`

Comment: `<<<` is for a herestring. File input redirection uses `<` as always.

Comment: and you need to read "awk", the preferred (e.g. non-perl) way of dealing with (essentially) tables in unix.  _then_ when you're comfortable with awk, you should download RDB, e.g. search for /rdb -- unix realational database managment, schaefer, manis and jorgenson.  it will change your life.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the builtin `read` for this:

```
cat /home/school.test | while read name class ; do 
    positionClient -name "$name" -class "$class"
done
```

I prefer the pipe with `cat` since using I/O redirection with a `while` loop looks a bit odd ("what is `done` doing with this file??"):

```
while read name class ; do 
    positionClient -name "$name" -class "$class"
done < /home/school.test
```

Note that you have to use the second approach if you want to share variables between the loop body and code after the loop. When using a pipe, the `while` loop will be executed in a subshell (in a different process) and all modifications to variables inside of the loop will be lost when the loop ends.

Comment: Using the redirect doesn't look odd at all, and avoids running in a subshell.

Comment: To add to @WilliamPursells comment, it also allows variables set in the loop to be used outside(as it is not a subshell).

Comment: @WilliamPursell: I agree with the subshell problem but what is `done` doing with the file? Also, having the input at the end of a code block is weird. And when the body of the loop is big, this is easily overlooked.

Comment: What about `while read name class ; do ..stuff..; done < /home/school.test` to avoid a **UUoC** (unnecessary use of `cat`) and spawning an additional separate subshell? (just to add formal terminology)

Answer (score 0):

if you insist on using the shell loop, then:

```
for line in `cat school.test`
do
    set -- $line   # $1 is NAME, and $2 is CLASS. 
    # NB since awk didn't distinguish separator, NO NEED to quote $1, $2
    positionClient -name $1 -class $2
done
```

OR, here's a one-liner:

```
awk 'BEGIN { fmt="positionClient -name %s -class %s\n"; }; { print fmt, $1, $2 }' school.test | sh -x
```

Answer (score -1):

There are various ways to get the values into different variables. One method is already mentioned in the other answers, i.e., using the built in `read`.

Allow me to explain another approach. Here is one approach using `awk`. It might not be the most optimal (because of the subshell thingy) but it works.

```
for line in `cat school.test`
do
    name=`echo $line | awk '{print $1}'`
    class=`echo $line | awk '{print $2}'`
    positionClient -name "$name" -class "$class"
done
```

Comment: question use of "optimal".  "optimal' should have less to do with PERFOMANCE, and more to to with SIMPLE to READ by a PERSON.  not that yours isn't and you've identified the SUBoptimality without reconizing thet a single awk, if you insist, could do the job.  see the use of "SET -- " below.

Comment: @MartyMcGowan: Your solution is good. And, I do understand how the `set --` works. But please help me understand how the `set` approach has a better readability than the `awk` approach? Also I mentioned, it was **one** approach and not the **only** approach.