# Separate string read from CSV into array is not working

Tags: bash, csv

So I have my CSV file which looks like that:

```
repo_name1,path1,branch1 branch2
```

I read it with following code:

```
INPUT=repos.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=','

[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read repo_name local_path branches
do
    printf "\n"
    echo "Repository name: $repo_name"
    echo "Local path: $local_path"
    cd $local_path
    for branch in $branches
    do
        echo branch
        printf "\n"
    done
done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

And I want to split branch1 and branch2 to an array in bash script.

I tried everything that I found on stackoverflow
[Loop through an array of strings in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8880603/loop-through-an-array-of-strings-in-bash),
[Split string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/split-string-into-an-array-in-bash),
[Reading a delimited string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293887/reading-a-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-bash)
, but nothing is working correctly and what I'm getting is array containing 1 element -> `branch1 branch2`

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have set `IFS=','` and trying to read space-separated array

Comment: Try `IFS=",$IFS"` to add the comma but keep the usual delimiters. (and `echo branch` should probably be `echo "$branch"`.)

Comment: `for branch in $branches` -- you are using IFS=, to split `$branches`, there are no commas in $branches so you only get one iteration through that loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this in two steps:

```sh
input=repos.csv

while IFS=, read -r repo path branchstr; do
    read -ra branches <<< "$branchstr"
    declare -p repo path branches
done < "$input"
```

resulting in

```
$ ./split
declare -- repo="repo_name1"
declare -- path="path1"
declare -a branches=([0]="branch1" [1]="branch2")
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.
Can you tell me how to get rid of this "declare" output?

Comment: @cropyeee It's the output of the `declare` command – an easy way to see what a variable contains. Just replace the `declare` line with whatever you want to do with `repo`, `path` and `branches`.