# GNU Make: How to set an array from a space-separated string?

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, gnu-make

> I'm writing a **Terminal** [Match-Anything Pattern Rule](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html#Match_002dAnything-Rules), i.e. `%::`, that, as expected, will run only if no other *target* is matched. In its *recipe* I want to iterate over makefile's *explicit targets* and check if the found pattern (`$*`) is the beginning of any other *target*

By now I'm successfully getting all desired targets in a *space-separated string* and storing it in a variable `TARGETS`, however I couldn't turn it in an array to be able to iterate over each word in the string.

> For instance
>
> ```
> %::
>    $(eval TARGETS ::= $(shell grep -Ph "^[^\t].*::.*##" ./Makefile | cut -d : -f 1 | sort))
>    echo $(TARGETS)
> ```
>
> gives me just what I was expecting:
>
> ```
> build clean compile deploy execute init run serve
> ```

### The Question

How could I iterate over each of `$(TARGET)` string words inside a `GNU Make 4.2.1` loop?

---

*I found a bunch of BASH solutions, but none of them worked in my tests:*

- [Reading a delimited string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9293887/2989289)
- [How to split one string into multiple strings separated by at least >one space in bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1469849/2989289)

Comment: You might be interested how bash make completion does it: https://github.com/scop/bash-completion/blob/master/completions/make

Comment: Loops are an alien concept in make. The real question would be: "Loop to do what?" to build a variable?, to check some values?. You may be forced to use some other language to process a loop (shell? Perl? python?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a really bad idea to use `eval` and `shell` inside a recipe.  A recipe is *already* a shell script so you should just use shell scripting.

It's not really clear exactly what you want to do.  If you want to do this in a recipe, you can use a shell loop:

```
%::
        TARGETS=$$(grep -Ph "^[^\t].*::.*##" ./Makefile | cut -d : -f 1 | sort); \
        for t in $$TARGETS; do \
             echo $$t; \
        done
```

If you want to do it *outside* of a recipe you can use the GNU make `foreach` function.

Comment: Note, neither make (including GNU make) _nor_ POSIX sh have such a thing as "array variable".  The GNU Bash shell does have array variables but they are not portable to other shells and have different syntax.

Comment: Great to know, Mad, now I'm aware of it! 
Thanks a lot for your fast and precise attention

Comment: Hey Mad, simple late bonus question: I've been trying `$(if $(filter $*, $$t), echo true, echo false)` inside `for`, but without success. How should I do that comparison? Thanks!

Comment: You cannot use make functions inside a recipe to operate on shell variables like `$t`.  How can that work?  They are completely separate programs.  Make will _first_ expand all make variables and functions in your recipe, _then_ it will invoke a shell and pass the fully-expanded script to the shell to run.  By the time the shell receives the script to run, all make content is gone.  The shell runs the script and exits, and make waits for it to exit and determines whether it worked by examining the exit code.

Comment: Oow, pretty interesting enlightenment about execution order. Thanks for your valuable attention, again, man!

Comment: Hello @MadScientist, I'm very sorry if I bother you, I see you are an expert on GNU, I have the same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77831453/how-to-work-around-with-issue-8192-chars-is-max-of-command-of-cmd-exe) , can you help me please? Thank you very much.