# How to work around with issue "8192 chars is max of command of cmd.exe"

Tags: gnu-make

I have a issue with this GNU make, code:

```
$(EXE):$(COMMON_INFO) $(LNKFILE)
    @echo [COMPILING]...
    @echo $(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD)
    @echo $(subst \,/, $(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD)) > list_file_to_build
```

Because max char of command for cmd.exe($(EXE)) is 8192 char so `list_file_to_build` not include all my file.
I try:

`$(foreach file,$(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD),$(subst \,/,$(file)) > list_file_to_build;)`

but not sloving problem. Please help me, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No amount of manipulation will help you, unless that manipulation makes the resulting string smaller.

All of make's functions are just that: string manipulation.  The input is a string or strings, and the result of those functions is a string.  Then that string is passed to the shell to execute.  On Windows, the maximum size of that string that you pass to the shell is more limited.

If you add to your makefile an `info` call to show the results of the string, you'll see that your changes don't help anything:

```
$(EXE):$(COMMON_INFO) $(LNKFILE)
        ...
        $(info echo $(subst \,/, $(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD)) > list_file_to_build)
        @echo $(subst \,/, $(CC_FILES_TO_BUILD)) > list_file_to_build
```

If the output generated by the `info` is >8192 bytes, it will fail.  Any changes you make have to result in the size of that string being <8192 bytes.

You effectively have two options:

If you have a sufficiently new version of GNU Make you can use [the `file` function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/File-Function.html) to write directly to the file: this type of situation is exactly why that function was created.  Since this is a make function that doesn't invoke a shell, there is effectively no limit to the size of the output.

The `file` function was added in GNU Make 4.0 (released >10 years ago).

If you don't have a new-enough GNU Make then you'll have to write in chunks by using the `words` function.  This is very tricky because you don't know how many "words" will send you over the limit, and there's not an easy way to loop through all the values.