# Bash and IFS: string split to an array with specific separator add an extra empty element

Tags: arrays, string, bash, shell, split

About split a string into an array we have two scenarios:

if the string has empty spaces how a separator, according with the following post:

- [Reading a space-delimited string into an array in Bash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293887/reading-a-space-delimited-string-into-an-array-in-bash)

So If I use:

```
string="Hello Unix World"
array1=($string)
echo ${array1[@]}
echo "size: '${#array1[@]}'"

read -a array2 <<< $string
echo ${array2[@]}
echo "size: '${#array2[@]}'"
```

The output is:

```
Hello Unix World
size: '3'
Hello Unix World
size: '3'
```

Both approaches works as expected.

Now, if the string has something different than an empty space how a separator, according with the following post:

- [How to split a string into an array in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10586153/how-to-split-a-string-into-an-array-in-bash)

So If I use:

```
path="/home/human/scripts"
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "$path"

echo "Approach 1"
echo ${array[@]}
echo "size: '${#array[@]}'"

echo "Approach 2"
for i in "${array[@]}"; do
   echo "$i"
done

echo "Approach 3"
for (( i=0; i < ${#array[@]}; ++i )); do
    echo "$i: ${array[$i]}"
done
```

It prints:

```
Approach 1
home human scripts    <--- apparently all is ok, but see the line just below!
size: '4'
Approach 2
                      <--- an empty element
home
human
scripts
Approach 3
0:                    <--- confirmed, the empty element
1: home
2: human
3: scripts
```

Why appears that empty element? How fix the command to avoid this situation?

Comment: The empty element produces no visible output with `echo $@`. `printf '%s\n' "${array[@]}"` would have given you the same output for approach 1 and approach 2.

Comment: a delimiter has a 'before' field and an 'after' field; when `/` is the delimiter this - `/home/human/scripts` - has 4x fields ... the empty string before the first `/`, and the other 3 fields that you know about; if the input was `//home/human/scripts/` you'd have 6 fields ... 2 empty strings + `home` + `human` + `scripts` + 1 empty string

Comment: I should say, too, that if you had proper quoted the array in approach 1, `echo "${array[@]}"` would have output ` home human scripts`, with the space separating the empty string from `home` visible. Without quotes, `echo` really does only get three arguments; the unquoted empty string "vanishes" during word-splitting.

Comment: I need iterate the array. Therefore is important avoid the empty element, and the string is a path for either MacOS or Linux.

Comment: @markp-fuso huge thanks for explanation.

Comment: fwiw, you'll see the same behavior with other tools/commands that use delimiters (eg, `cut` and `awk`) or that use `IFS` to split the input (eg, `read` - see konsolebox's example)

Comment: @markp-fuso just in case about `the empty string before the first /` part of your first comment - in the `path="/home/human/scripts"` declaration -  it starts with `/home` and not with ` /home`

Comment: fwiw, I typed `/home` (no leading space) ... the formatted text just looks like it has a leading space (like in your comment, too :-)

Comment: @chepner correct about the second comment - it was tested. In general the confusion came from about why appeared the empty space if there is no an empty space before of the first `/` character.

Comment: @markp-fuso in that case `//home/human/scripts/` returns 5, not 6. I tested.

Comment: The empty string is not the same as a space. The leading space in the output of `echo "${array[@]}"` comes from `echo` itself, not the array.

Comment: `array1=($string)` is buggy **in general**. See [BashPitfalls #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#hosts.3D.28_.24.28aws_....29_.29)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your string split into 4 parts: an empty one, and the three words.

```
path="/home/human/scripts"
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "$path"
declare -p array
```

Output:

```
declare -a array=([0]="" [1]="home" [2]="human" [3]="scripts")
```

There are many ways to fix it.  One is to delete the empty values.  Another is to exclude the beginning slash before splitting.

```
for i in "${!array[@]}"; do
    [[ ${array[i]} ]] || unset 'array[i]'
done
```

Or

```
IFS='/' read -r -a array <<< "${path#/}"
```

The first one is adaptable to path forms were slashes are repeated not only in the beginning.

Comment: I used your second approach. Thanks. Can you expand the idea about why appeared the empty element?

Comment: Because it's a component of the string you split. Just because the strings *starts* with `/` doesn't mean the initial `/` is treated differently.

Comment: Can you explain how works `"${path#/}"`? specially the `"#/` part.

Comment: @chepner now I see ... sorry very tired to realise about that. Thanks

Comment: It's one of those [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) methods.

Answer (score 1):

Just to pile on with what is really a formatted comment:

The manual (in [3.5.7 Word Splitting](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Word-Splitting)) describes IFS as a "field **terminator**":

> The shell treats each character of `$IFS` as a delimiter, and splits the results of the other expansions into words using these characters as field terminators.

For `IFS=/ read -a fields <<< "/home/user"`, the first field is the empty string terminated by the first slash.