# Redirector "<<<" in Ubuntu?

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dash-shell

I'm getting this error

> Syntax error: redirection unexpected

in the line:

```
 if grep -q "^127.0.0." <<< "$RESULT"
```

How I can run this in Ubuntu?

Comment: Is not redirection a single, left angle bracket?   <

Comment: Code goes from left to right. Been a while, but if I remember correct it is `>> "$RESULT"` to redirect it.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that command? What is the value of `$RESULT`?

Comment: @DaveNewman `grep` can read a file without any redirection.

Comment: @Ansgar - Understood, but the OP appeared to be asking about redirection.

Comment: You should escape the dots "^127\.0\.0\." Otherwise you match strings like "127X0Y0Z"

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950268/what-does-the-bash-operator-i-e-triple-less-than-sign-mean

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if grep -q "^127.0.0." <<< "$RESULT"
then
    echo IF-THEN
fi
```

is a Bash-specific thing.  If you are using a different bourne-compatable shell, try:

```
if echo "$RESULT" | grep -q "^127.0.0."
then
    echo IF-THEN
fi
```

Answer (score 35):

`<<<` is a bash-specific redirection operator (so it's not specific to Ubuntu).  The [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings) refers to it as a "Here String", a variant of the ["Here Document"](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Documents).

> **3.6.7 Here Strings**
>
> A variant of here documents, the format is:
>
> *<<< word*
>
> The *word* is expanded and supplied to the command on its
> standard input.

A simple example:

```
$ cat <<< hello
hello
```

If you're getting an error, it's likely that you're executing the command using a shell other than bash. If you have `#!/bin/sh` at the top of your script, try changing it to `#!/bin/bash`.

If you try to use it with `/bin/sh`, it probably assumes the `<<` refers to a "here document", and then sees an unexpected `<` after that, resulting in the "Syntax error: redirection unexpected" message that you're seeing.

zsh and ksh also support the `<<<` syntax.

Comment: ksh supports it. dash doesn’t.

Comment: Would it be accurate to say it's a shorthand for `cat <(echo "hello")`? (I'm just asking to deepen my understanding)

Comment: @Sridhar-Sarnobat: Not quite. `cat <<< hello` invokes `cat` with no arguments, with stdin redirected from a temporary file containing `hello` followed by a newline. `cat <(echo hello)` invokes `cat` with a single argument, which is the name of a pseudo-file from which it can read the same data. `cat` behaves similarly with no arguments and stdin redirected vs. with a single argument naming a file to be read, but other commands can behave differently. For example, on my system `ls -l /proc/self/fd/0 <<<hello` lists a symlink to the temporary file, and `echo <(echo hello)` prints `/dev/fd/63`.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me on Ubuntu, if I complete you IF block:

```
if grep -q "^127.0.0." <<< "$RESULT"; then echo ""; fi
```

Comment: What does <<< do? This may be something new to me.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462317/bash-syntax-error-redirection-unexpected

Comment: not run in Ubuntu: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2462317/bash-syntax-error-redirection-unexpected

Comment: Not Ubuntu problem, but it doesn't run in dash. in bash works fine (since I have in Ubuntu default bash).